# Typecasting a dynamic type to a static type in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting, c++-cli, type-conversion

I have a function in C++/CLI that accepts a static object, which contains a dynamic field. I would like to use this dynamic field.

If the real type of the dynamic field is known during compile time, is it possible to typecast it to the known type? How would I go about doing so?

I do know that C++/CLI does not allow you to "consume" dynamic types, but does this also apply to type conversions?

I am trying to avoid using 3rd party libraries, and would like to keep things simple if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run across a c# `dynamic` object in C++/CLI, just think of it as a type of `System::Object^`.

If you know what type you expect it to be, you can then use `safe_cast` to cast it.

C# code

```
dynamic dynamicList = new List<int>();
```

C++/CLI code

```
List<int>^ staticList = safe_cast<List<int>^>(dynamicList);
```

Expect an `InvalidCastException` to be thrown if you are incorrect.